# struct parametr in function gcc

Tags: c, gcc

I wrote some code and works perfectly using g++ compiler, but when I use gcc, it throws an error `Unknow type name 'Image' in void load_image(FILE*, Image*);`

Here's a part of my header file:

```
struct Image {
    struct FileHeader file_header;
    struct InfoHeader info_header;
    struct RGBQuads rgbquads;
    struct Pixel** pixel;
    struct Pixel* pixels_array;
};

void load_image(FILE*, Image*);
```

So I cant understand whats the problem. I was trying to write using C rules.

Comment: c wants `typedef struct ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are compiling the program as a C program. If so then you have to write

```
void load_image(FILE*, struct Image*);
```

Another approach is to use typedef for the structure. For example

```
typedef struct Image {
    struct FileHeader file_header;
    struct InfoHeader info_header;
    struct RGBQuads rgbquads;
    struct Pixel** pixel;
    struct Pixel* pixels_array;
} Image;

void load_image(FILE*, Image*);
```

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about `struct` in parameters

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
void load_image(FILE*,struct Image*);
```

Else use

```
typedef struct Image NEW_NAME;
```